# daily returns of stocks and average returns calculated from daily returns (PYTHON)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a excel that named on DF0. DF0 includes the first trading date of each stock and the daily prices from the first trading date to date.

Excel Columns Name: DATE , CODE, CLOSEPRICE, FIRST TRADING DAY

**My problem is i am trying to calculate their 30 - 60 - 90 day return per stock. I am trying to find the average returns of 30 - 60 - 90 days from the daily returns I calculated. The most important criterion here is that the calculations will be made from the start date of their trading per stock.**

**But, (thirty_day_prices[1:] / thirty_day_prices[-1]) - 1 calculating wrong daily return. How can arrange part of my code according to calculate daily return?**

You see my code below;

```
df = df0.set_index('CODE')['DATE'].to_dict()


start_dates = df0.set_index('CODE')['FIRST TRADING DAY'].to_dict()

results = {}
for code in start_dates.keys():
    start_date = start_dates[code]
    portion_df = df0.loc[df0['CODE'] == code]
    if not portion_df.empty:
        prices = portion_df.loc[portion_df['DATE'] >= start_date, 'CLOSEPRICE'].values
        if len(prices) > 0:
            thirty_day_prices = prices[0:min(len(prices),30)]
            sixty_day_prices = prices[0:min(len(prices),60)]
            ninety_day_prices = prices[0:min(len(prices),90)]
            thirty_day_tot = (thirty_day_prices[1:] / thirty_day_prices[-1]) - 1  if len(thirty_day_prices) > 1 else np.nan
            print(thirty_day_tot)
            sixty_day_tot = (sixty_day_prices[1:] / sixty_day_prices[-1]) - 1 if len(sixty_day_prices) > 1 else np.nan
            ninety_day_tot = (ninety_day_prices[1:] / ninety_day_prices[-1]) - 1 if len(ninety_day_prices) > 1 else np.nan
            avg_thirty_day_return = np.nanmean(thirty_day_tot)
            avg_sixty_day_return = np.nanmean(sixty_day_tot)
            avg_ninety_day_return = np.nanmean(ninety_day_tot)
            results[code] = {'FIRST TRADING DAY': start_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'),
                             'AVERAGE RETURN FOR 30 DAY FROM START DATE': f'{avg_thirty_day_return:.0%}' if not np.isnan(avg_thirty_day_return) else 'No data',
                             'AVERAGE RETURN FOR 60 DAY FROM START DATE': f'{avg_sixty_day_return:.0%}' if not np.isnan(avg_sixty_day_return) else 'No data',
                             'AVERAGE RETURN FOR 90 DAY FROM START DATE': f'{avg_ninety_day_return:.0%}' if not np.isnan(avg_ninety_day_return) else 'No data'}
        else:
            print(f"No data available for {code} with starting date {start_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')}")
    else:
        print(f"No data available for {code}")

wanted_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results, orient='index')
wanted_df.index.name = 'CODE'
```

My Dataframe;

My start date is: 22.12.2022 (dd.mm.yyyy) for APPLE

My start date is: 16.11.2022 (dd.mm.yyyy) for HARLEY

My start date is: 21.10.2021 (dd.mm.yyyy) for META

| DATE | CODE | CLOSE PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08.06.2023 | APPLE | 8.5 |
| 07.06.2023 | APPLE | 7 |
| 06.06.2023 | APPLE | 9.3 |
| 05.06.2023 | APPLE | 12 |
| 04.06.2023 | APPLE | 3 |
| ...... | APPLE | ... |
| 22.12.2022 | APPLE | 25 |
| 08.06.2023 | HARLEY | 4 |
| 07.06.2023 | HARLEY | 2 |
| 06.06.2023 | HARLEY | 1 |
| 05.06.2023 | HARLEY | 5 |
| 04.06.2023 | HARLEY | 9.5 |
| ... | HARLEY | .... |
| 16.11.2022 | HARLEY | 4 |
| 08.06.2023 | META | 1.1 |
| 07.06.2023 | META | 2 |
| 06.06.2023 | META | 1 |
| 05.06.2023 | META | 15 |
| 04.06.2023 | META | 65 |
| ... | META | ... |
| 21.10.2021 | META | 5 |

**As an example, I want to calculate daily return for 30 days from closing prices from 22.12.2022 for apple. I then want to average in the calculated daily return for these 30 days.**

My expected output;

| CODE | FIRST TRADING DAY | AVERAGE RETURN FOR 30 DAY FROM START DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| APPLE | 22.12.2022 | %5 |

Comment: Can you provide an example of how it's returning it wrong? Or a sample of the dataframe so we can do things to it with similar results as you have?

I think you can do `thirty_day_tot = (thirty_day_prices/thirty_day_prices[-1])-1`

Comment: Updated Sample. 
As an example, I want to calculate daily return for 30 days from closing prices from 22.12.2022 for apple. I then want to average in the calculated daily return for these 30 days.

Comment: How do you calculate the daily return? Which is the formula used for that?

Comment: thirty_day_tot = (thirty_day_prices[1:] / thirty_day_prices[-1]) - 1  if len(thirty_day_prices) > 1 else np.nan

Comment: I was thinking of the mathematical formula. My question is, how do you know it's giving you a wrong result?

Comment: What's the output you get?